# Problemas na execução de Aplicação Java no Docker

Tags: java, docker

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Criei um container com 1GB de memória e 16GB de Swap, estou usando o Oracle JDK 8 Update 171 (64 bits) com S.O Debian 9.

Defini os parametros do Java_OPTS para que a JVM leia a CGROUPS.

O container esta subindo corretamente com os parametros que passei. Dentro do container consigo subir a minha aplicação Springboot duas vezes (02 processos), sendo um com 08GB (XMS e XMX) e o outro com 7GB (XMS e XMX) sem problemas.

Pelo que entendi no container tenho 01GB RAM + 14GB SWAP = 15GB total.

Mas quando tento subir somente uma aplicação com 9 ou 10GB (XMS e XMX), a aplicação não sobre e me gera o arquivo hs... informando que não pode alocar memória.

Como é possivel subir 02 processos com 15GB (8+7), mas não sobre 01 processo com 09GB????

Já tentei aumentar a RAM para 10GB e swap de 6GB.
Já configurei memória reservada, mas nada deu certo.

Testei a mesma aplicação em um Debian fora do container, sendo que o Debian possui 1GB (RAM) e 16GB Swap e consegui subir a mesma com XMX de 12GB.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Beleza? Antes, tenho só uma dúvida, pq duas app dentro de um container?